# Linear equation solving leads to program exit (x64)

Tags: ilnumerics

I have some problem with linear equation solving. I have two matrices: A and B.
The dimension of system is 24 ("A" is 24x24 matrix). 
Then i call "ILMath.linsolve(A, B)", the program is closing unexpectedly without any exceptions or messages. 
I have found that this problem present for platform target x64 and is absent for x86. 
Can someone comment this? Bug or misunderstanding of ILNumerics usage?

OS Windows 7 (64 bit) on intel core i7.

Below are the matrices that result to error  (can't find how to attach files). On x86 platform the result is NaN, but this is acceptable (as opposed to program exit).

P.S. may be related to https://mediaautomat.de/mantis/view.php?id=178

file: testMatrixSolver_[24,24].txt

```
A = 
<Double> [24,24]
(:,:) 1e+004 * 
0,00000    1,44682    0,88271    1,08754    2,84771    2,80983    3,64760    3,54584    4,21863    4,78911    4,19593    4,60941    5,16538    4,90552    4,87245    5,02034    5,42170    5,87407    5,85920    5,89104    6,08131    6,26784    6,56444    0,00010 
1,44682    0,00000    1,91625    1,33214    1,99742    2,83174    3,21557    4,10363    4,04118    3,84300    4,18627    3,99828    4,35512    4,61547    4,78964    5,29765    5,85039    5,70449    6,17333    6,30469    5,70157    6,30999    6,41938    0,00010 
0,88271    1,91625    0,00000    0,82227    2,68614    2,16273    3,20411    2,74905    3,65844    4,71273    3,56469    4,29182    5,02270    4,43590    4,30925    4,36273    4,80273    5,45878    5,30938    5,35701    5,80569    5,84445    6,29503    0,00010 
1,08754    1,33214    0,82227    0,00000    1,93358    1,83034    2,66562    2,95360    3,30749    4,07693    3,32752    3,73749    4,44312    4,05599    4,05870    4,39840    4,99967    5,20256    5,43769    5,58527    5,44640    5,76367    6,09578    0,00010 
2,84771    1,99742    2,68614    1,93358    0,00000    1,82125    1,46606    3,58486    2,52773    2,33607    2,87539    2,17512    2,76087    3,01279    3,40940    4,43698    5,33298    4,37984    5,60471    5,94724    4,26287    5,41505    5,35821    0,00010 
2,80983    2,83174    2,16273    1,83034    1,82125    0,00000    1,33559    1,89433    1,62275    3,64206    1,59220    2,62374    3,77787    2,53021    2,41331    2,99133    3,95767    3,80246    4,35438    4,74840    4,32867    4,50010    4,99090    0,00010 
3,64760    3,21557    3,20411    2,66562    1,46606    1,33559    0,00000    2,94252    1,12597    2,57844    1,59661    1,33467    2,61332    1,65705    2,05491    3,39554    4,54986    3,15292    4,77203    5,30888    3,31932    4,34527    4,34657    0,00010 
3,54584    4,10363    2,74905    2,95360    3,58486    1,89433    2,94252    0,00000    2,52378    5,09231    2,01864    4,00447    5,12100    3,36273    2,71871    1,93348    2,42875    4,11021    3,05014    3,25482    5,09454    4,05941    5,23146    0,00010 
4,21863    4,04118    3,65844    3,30749    2,52773    1,62275    1,12597    2,52378    0,00000    3,36997    0,62578    1,78442    3,21093    0,98858    0,96613    2,47528    3,80680    2,33181    3,96235    4,65882    3,04762    3,40287    3,69050    0,00010 
4,78911    3,84300    4,71273    4,07693    2,33607    3,64206    2,57844    5,09231    3,36997    0,00000    3,89486    1,79566    0,78164    3,19042    3,98246    5,35377    6,19888    4,27500    6,28968    6,62640    3,32117    5,67391    4,94431    0,00010 
4,19593    4,18627    3,56469    3,32752    2,87539    1,59220    1,59661    2,01864    0,62578    3,89486    0,00000    2,38476    3,76017    1,44043    0,89166    1,91209    3,26664    2,46461    3,46354    4,16939    3,46091    3,16292    3,83318    0,00010 
4,60941    3,99828    4,29182    3,73749    2,17512    2,62374    1,33467    4,00447    1,78442    1,79566    2,38476    0,00000    1,51218    1,47929    2,36528    4,04614    5,19817    2,79991    5,28332    5,86071    2,30655    4,41114    3,79334    0,00010 
5,16538    4,35512    5,02270    4,44312    2,76087    3,77787    2,61332    5,12100    3,21093    0,78164    3,76017    1,51218    0,00000    2,83580    3,70818    5,20484    6,11432    3,80128    6,16799    6,56776    2,64560    5,36160    4,41525    0,00010 
4,90552    4,61547    4,43590    4,05599    3,01279    2,53021    1,65705    3,36273    0,98858    3,19042    1,44043    1,47929    2,83580    0,00000    1,00339    2,91194    4,25484    1,58188    4,26136    5,04277    2,13430    3,15454    2,91422    0,00010 
4,87245    4,78964    4,30925    4,05870    3,40940    2,41331    2,05491    2,71871    0,96613    3,98246    0,89166    2,36528    3,70818    1,00339    0,00000    1,96941    3,40757    1,61655    3,41133    4,27827    2,87243    2,52115    3,05316    0,00010 
5,02034    5,29765    4,36273    4,39840    4,43698    2,99133    3,39554    1,93348    2,47528    5,35377    1,91209    4,04614    5,20484    2,91194    1,96941    0,00000    1,53942    3,01426    1,66056    2,52905    4,48908    2,36774    4,13186    0,00010 
5,42170    5,85039    4,80273    4,99967    5,33298    3,95767    4,54986    2,42875    3,80680    6,19888    3,26664    5,19817    6,11432    4,25484    3,40757    1,53942    0,00000    4,25928    0,86437    1,04855    5,56686    3,18305    5,11819    0,00010 
5,87407    5,70449    5,45878    5,20256    4,37984    3,80246    3,15292    4,11021    2,33181    4,27500    2,46461    2,79991    3,80128    1,58188    1,61655    3,01426    4,25928    0,00000    4,01693    4,96341    1,91873    2,09750    1,51094    0,00010 
5,85920    6,17333    5,30938    5,43769    5,60471    4,35438    4,77203    3,05014    3,96235    6,28968    3,46354    5,28332    6,16799    4,26136    3,41133    1,66056    0,86437    4,01693    0,00000    1,26782    5,43508    2,61931    4,77691    0,00010 
5,89104    6,30469    5,35701    5,58527    5,94724    4,74840    5,30888    3,25482    4,65882    6,62640    4,16939    5,86071    6,56776    5,04277    4,27827    2,52905    1,04855    4,96341    1,26782    0,00000    6,11622    3,76101    5,64400    0,00010 
6,08131    5,70157    5,80569    5,44640    4,26287    4,32867    3,31932    5,09454    3,04762    3,32117    3,46091    2,30655    2,64560    2,13430    2,87243    4,48908    5,56686    1,91873    5,43508    6,11622    0,00000    3,82539    2,06788    0,00010 
6,26784    6,30999    5,84445    5,76367    5,41505    4,50010    4,34527    4,05941    3,40287    5,67391    3,16292    4,41114    5,36160    3,15454    2,52115    2,36774    3,18305    2,09750    2,61931    3,76101    3,82539    0,00000    2,56155    0,00010 
6,56444    6,41938    6,29503    6,09578    5,35821    4,99090    4,34657    5,23146    3,69050    4,94431    3,83318    3,79334    4,41525    2,91422    3,05316    4,13186    5,11819    1,51094    4,77691    5,64400    2,06788    2,56155    0,00000    0,00010 
0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00010    0,00000 
B = 
<Double> [24,1]
(:,:) 1e+004 * 
1,43198 
1,76503 
2,28512 
2,32261 
3,60803 
3,98305 
4,57855 
4,72375 
5,18107 
5,20678 
5,21228 
5,31666 
5,62346 
5,71215 
5,75390 
5,93499 
6,23050 
6,47977 
6,53616 
6,54298 
6,54379 
6,76731 
6,87920 
0,00010
```

Code for testing and parsing

```
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        try
        {
            TEST();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    private static void TEST()
    {
        var curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\";

        Console.WriteLine("\r\nSolving equation (Dimension 24)\r\n");

        a = readMatrixA("matrixSample_[24,24].txt", 10000);
        b = readMatrixB("matrixSample_[24,24].txt", 10000);

        ILMath.linsolve(a, b);

        Console.WriteLine("\r\nPress any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static ILArray<double> readMatrixA(string filePath, double m)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            throw new Exception("File not found: " + filePath);

        var reader = new StreamReader(filePath);

        ILArray<double> result = new double[0,0];

        string line;

        var row=0;
        var col=0;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains("A = "))
            {
                reader.ReadLine();
                reader.ReadLine();
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }

            if (line == null || line.Contains("B ="))
                break;

            var parts = line.Split(' ');
            foreach (var part in parts.Where(part => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(part.Trim())))
                result[row, col++] = Double.Parse(part.Trim(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * m;

            row++;
            col = 0;
        }

        reader.Close();
        return result;
    }

    private static ILArray<double> readMatrixB(string filePath, double m)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            throw new Exception("File not found: " + filePath);


        var reader = new StreamReader(filePath);

        ILArray<double> result = new double[0,0];

        string line;

        var dataStart = false;
        var row=0;
        var col=0;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains("B = ") && !dataStart)
            {
                reader.ReadLine();
                reader.ReadLine();
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                dataStart = true;
            }

            if (!dataStart || line == null)
                continue;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim()) || line.Contains("C = "))
                break;

            var parts = line.Split(' ');
            foreach (var part in parts.Where(part => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(part.Trim())))
                result[row, col++] = Double.Parse(part.Trim(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * m;

            row++;
            col = 0;
        }

        reader.Close();
        return result;
    }

}
// ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
```

Comment: +1 I like the way you are reading in the elements.